# Order una consulta Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

He creado un modelo con su migración para juego.  Quiero ordenar el resultado por fecha, intento con

```
$data = juego::all()->orderBy('fecha', 'desc')->get();
```

Me aparece el error

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist "

Comment: Al poner `all()` ejecutas la consulta, que devuelve una colección, por eso el error. Debes quitar ese `all()`, y dejar que la consulta se ejecute con el `get()` del final.

Comment: Puedes decirme cual sería la instrucción completa?

Comment: Si vas a : `tuapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php` notarás como el método `orderBy` no forma parte de esta clase por lo tanto es lógico el mensaje que obtienes ya que intentas invocarlo sobre una colección; por otro lado si aún con `all` deseas obtener un ordenamiento tienes diponibles los métodos `sortBy` así como `sortByDesc`

Answer (score 1):

Al poner `all()` ejecutas la consulta, que devuelve una colección, por eso el error, pues `orderBy` no es un método de la clase Collection.

Esto ya es la consulta, y devolverá todos los registros del model `juego`:

```php
juego::all();
```

Cuando quieres agregar algún modificador a tu consulta, puedes ir encadenándolos, y finalmente ejecutar la consulta con el método `get()` (o `paginate()` también puede ser, pero no `all()`, que es un método estático).

Entonces, debes quitar ese `all()`, y dejar que la consulta se ejecute con el `get()` del final.

```php
juego::orderBy('fecha', 'desc')->get();
```